# Precompile / preload cached fragments in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

Using Rails 3.1.1 and Herkou

I have 1.000 products in my app. They all have a very slow controller which is effectively solved by fragment caching. Although the data doesn't change very often, it still needs to expire (which I do by sweeping) periodically, in my case once a week.

Now, after sweeping the cached views I don't want my users to create the new fragments by trying to access the products one after another (takes about 6-8 secs at the first load, 2-3 sec for the cached load). I assume I can do that with some sort of script that will load each Product Page one by one and thus make the server create those fragments.

I can imagine this can be handled in three ways:

1. Run a script on my local machine that will try to access each url with some sort of get-command - Downside: Not very pretty and will affect visitor stats in a way I would not prefer.
2. Run the same type script on the server after the sweeper, that will load each Product. How can I do that, in that case?
3. Using a smart Rails command to do this automatically. Is there such an elegant command?

Comment: I'm dealing with a similar issue myself and am finding that there are other ways to optimize my code for faster initial load times instead of just caching. Have you considered some performance tweaks or moving some of the logic to an async client side request?

Comment: I am working on multiple solutions but caching seems the best way right now...

Comment: Perhaps you could set up another virtual host (e.g. precache.mydomain.com) and a simple script could hit that server, to keep the traffic out of your logs.  The trick would be to ensure that the generated fragments from that server get used by the public server.

Answer (score 0):

I made this script and it works. The "product.slug" is because I have friendly_id installed. It will produce url-variables with names such as www.mydomain.com/productabc-123/ which will be read by Nokogiri (Nokogiri gem is needed for this solution).

PLEASE NOTE THAT I SWITCHED FROM FRAGMENT CACHING TO ACTION CACHING IN THIS SOLUTION (as opposed to the question, where I am using fragment caching). The important difference for this is when I check the cache `if Rails.cache.exist?('views/www.mydomain.com/' + product.slug)`. For fragment_caching it should be the fragment name there instead.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

Product.all.each do |product|
  url = 'http://www.mydomain.com/' + product.slug  
  begin      
    if Rails.cache.exist?('views/www.mydomain.com/' + product.slug)     
      puts url + " is already in cache"
    else
      doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
      puts "Reads " + url
# Verifies if the caching worked. Only for trouble shooting
      if Rails.cache.exist?('views/www.mydomain.com/' + product.slug)     
        puts "--->" + url + " is NOW in the cache"
      else
        puts "--->" + url + " is still not in the cache!"
      end
      sleep 1
    end
  rescue
    puts 'Normal rescue of ' + url
  rescue Timeout::Error
    puts 'Timeout rescue of ' + url
    puts 'Sleep for 5 sec'
    sleep 5
    retry
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a script that runs as rake task, or better yet a worker, that runs and curls the page. There is no need to include a gem when you can just call curl

```
`curl -A "CacheRefresher" #{ENV['HOSTNAME']}/api/v1/#{klass.name.underscore.pluralize}/#{id} >/dev/null 2>&1`
```

Comment: Sounds like he wants to avoid bloating his access logs with non-user hits.  This approach would put all that extra traffic into the logs.

Comment: IMO trying to circumvent that is going to create more problems then it solves. He can just add a user agent to the request and make sure to filter it out of stats, like you would with any other bot.  `curl -A "CacheRefresher"`